# Displaying servlet on HTML page

Tags: java, servlets

I have a simple servlet that prints out basic HTML headers with some text.  On the main html page, I have it set up so that when a submit button is pressed, it goes to the servlet page.

How do I go about displaying that servlet within the main page and not making the user press a submit button to display it?

Answer (score 1):

Just perform the job in `doGet()` method instead of `doPost()` and call the servlet directly by its URL in browser address bar instead of the HTML page.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, using a servlet to emit HTML is a poor practice. Put that HTML in a JSP file and let the servlet forward to that JSP. This offers better separation of Java code and HTML markup and thus easier maintenance without the need to fiddle with quoted strings and other HTML specifics. This is in detail demonstrated in the abovelinked Servlets wiki page.

Answer (score 0):

To request a Servlet you use the URL that is configured in the deployment descriptor (or annotations in the most recent version). If you intend that the default page of the website be your servlet then you simply configure the mapping so that the default maps to your servlet.

```
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```